# MVVM Light TextView two-way binding in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: binding, mvvm-light

Has anyone successfully implemented a two-way binding on a `TextView` with MVVM Light? Two-way works perfectly fine with `EditView`, but the moment I try two-way binding with `TextView` - only one way binding works. Does anyone have any insight as to why, please?

View Model:

```
private string _someField;
public string SomeField
{
    get { return _someField; }
    set { Set(ref _someField, value); }
}
```

View:

```
private EditText _editableText;
public EditText EditableText;
{
  get { return _editableTex ?? (_editableTex = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1)); }
}

private TextView _simpleText
public TextView SimpleText
{
  get { return _simpleText ?? (_simpleText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textDateDisplay)); }
}

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(() => vm.SomeField, () => EditableText.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay)); 
    bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(() => vm.SomeField, () => SimpleText.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay));
}
```

No errors are thrown. But when I change (in code) of the `View` the text of the `EditableText` (`EditableText.Text="asdf";`) the corresponding set `{ Set(ref _someField, value); }` triggers in the `VewModel`. It also triggers, naturally, if I just type in the `EditText` widget.

However, when I change (in code) the text property of the `SimpleText (SimpleText.Text="2145";)` it does not trigger the corresponding set.

Does anyone know why?

Thank you very much for help,
mike

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a two-way binding with `TextView`s, because they doesn't allow input by user.

When you are using MVVM pattern you should never update the view. You should update the bound model property. So you should replace `SimpleText.Text = "2145";` with `vm.SomeField = "2145";`.